# How to go for the architecture?

Tags: java, node.js, architecture, high-availability

I am designing an application that needs to work on the web as well as on mobiles.

The application shall work something like this :

The mobile applications shall consume the webservices for fetching and submitting data on the servers.

On the other hand, i also want to develop a web application that shall be consuming the webservices for the same purpose.

So, i need to go for SOA.

Upon googling, i found many architectures. Typically people opt for Node.js for mobile applications and java frameworks for web apps.

Also i am looking to go for highly scalable architecture.

Please suggest what should be idle architecture in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you question is probably too general. However the modern approach is indeed to create the services layer that exposes RESTfull API (e.g. JSON based) and then create as many as you want applications that use this API.

You can develop web application for "big" browser, other web application oriented for smartphones and probably mobile application for each popular platform (there are 2) that call this API.

There are a lot of ways to create AJAX-based application (JQuery, ExtJS, Node.js, Play!, GWT and more), so the choice depends on your needs, taste, expertise.